# If $f(n)= \binom{n}{0}a^{n-1}-..+(-1)^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1}a^{0}$ ,Then $f(2007)+f(2008) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $\displaystyle a= \frac{1}{3^{223}}+1$ and $\displaystyle f(n)= \binom{n}{0}a^{n-1}-\binom{n}{1}a^{n-2}+...........+(-1)^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1}a^{0}$
>
> Then value of $f(2007)+f(2008) = $

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Multiply both side by $a\;,$ We get

$$af(n) = \underbrace{\binom{n}{0}a^{n}-\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}+...........+(-1)^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1}a+(-1)^n}_{\bf{(a-1)^n}}+(-1)^{n+1}$$

So we get $$af(n)=(a-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}\Rightarrow f(n) = \frac{(a-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}}{a}$$

So $$f(2007)+f(2008) = \frac{1}{a}\left[(a-1)^{2007}+1+(a-1)^{2008}-1\right]$$

So we get $$f(2007)+f(2008) = \frac{(a-1)^{2007}\cdot a}{a} = (a-1)^{2007}=3^{-223\times 2007}$$

My Solution did not match here.

Where i have done Wrong, Help me

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your title

Comment: And you havent added $(-1)^n$ on LHS

Comment: I solved it and I too got the same answer. What is the correct answer?